# Cython/C++Qt interfacing

Tags: c++, c, qt, cython

I achieved to compile a small test on Cython so that it worked, but I didn't figure out how to interface Cython with QtC++ (in both ways). I remarked that it generates a very long C file and not C++ files. Is it possible to do such an interface?
Like for example let's say I want to declare a QString in Cython, can I do that? Can I declare a custom object from a .h file that is elsewhere? Is that even possible in C?

And backwards, can I call in C++/Qt the functions/objects/methods from the Cython (C)?

Comment: Cython translate .py code to .c hence its name, c'ython, and not cpp'ython. Now, you want to access some Qt features, so ask yourself how to do it from Python, and PyQt could be the answer. If you really want to add C++ source to the cython's generated one, whether from Qt API or not, you could simply `read the doc` [Cython: Wrapping C++](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html).

Comment: @ValeryS. - ummmm... It's completely possible to generate a cpp file with Cython (and that's exactly what's happening in the docs you linked)

Comment: yep, you're right ! `--cplus` switch do the trick ; never used it myself, thanks.